# Is there a limit to the number of GPUs I can use?

Tags: rendering, gpu, hardware

I'm putting together a mining-like render build with over 10 GPUs.
And I would like to ask is there a limit of gpu's I can use on given time.
I am asking this because I can go with like 4 680's (Each with 1500 Cuda Cores).